# UIPopoverController - presentPopoverFromRect that is inside s scaling/scrolling view?

Tags: uiscrollview, uipopovercontroller

I have a scaling/scrolling UIScrollview that I can place views on (think Drawing objets, Circles, squares, etc) I place a square on there and tap and Hold, menu comes up and I select Properties. I pass in the square.frame for the Rect and the popover looks great where it can fit in the UIScrollView.

Now I scale the UIScrollView so that the Square is bigger than the visible area on the screen.  Tap and Hold, select properties, and the Popover is Presented somewhere, though not anywhere I can see.

I'm not sure how to detect from the Square's perspective if its bigger than the visible area of the super.view's zoomed in area and present the Popover from a different Rect.

Zoomed Out, square is completely visible and has room for popover on canvas

```
self.frame:                              {{0, 659.959}, {1846.72, 1388.04}}
self.superview.frame:                    {{0, 0},       {1024,    1024}}
self.superview.superview.frame:          {{0, 44},      {1024,    704}}
self.superview.superview.superview.frame:{{0, 0},       {1024,    748}}
```

Zoomed In, square is covering all of screen

```
self.frame:                              {{0, 659.959}, {1846.72, 1388.04}}
self.superview.frame:                    {{0, 0},       {3180.31, 3180.31}}
self.superview.superview.frame:          {{0, 44},      {1024, 704}}
self.superview.superview.superview.frame:{{0, 0},       {1024, 748}}
```

Max Zoom, though scrolled so there is room for popover on canvas

```
self.frame:                              {{0, 659.96}, {1822.62, 1369.96}}
self.superview.frame:                    {{0, 0},      {4096, 4096}}
self.superview.superview.frame:          {{0, 44},     {1024, 704}}
self.superview.superview.superview.frame:{{0, 0},      {1024, 748}}
```

There does not seem to be a difference in the last toe to really tell that the square is coving the screen vs only a smidgin of it visible.

Any Suggestions welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it depends on which view the popover controller is being displayed, but you could try converting the Squares frame from the scrollview to the view displaying the popover using

```
- (CGRect)convertRect:(CGRect)rect fromView:(UIView *)view
```

Comment: Thanks, this works, though was inconsistant in placement with larger popovers.